# Vigenere's Cipher in C (CS50)

Tags: c, vigenere, cs50

I have been stuck on this for a while now, I thought I had it working several times only to find more things I forgot. Basically the problem set was to create the Vigenere Cipher using C, the rules can be found [here](http://cdn.cs50.net/2015/x/psets/2/pset2/pset2.html#parlez_vous_fran%C3%A7ais)

I basically have it working it will only allow the correct characters and if the keyword is the same length as the message all is good.

The issue I am having is figuring a way to reset the looping of the keyword while the message is being encrypted, so if I enter a keyword 'A' and the message 'This is a test' the encrypted message should read 'This is a test' since 'A' is worth zero shifts along the ASCII table.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char * keyWord[]) {
  int cipher[64], i, j, k, l;
  char message[128];

  // Validation - using alphaCheck Function
  if (argc != 2 || alphaCheck(keyWord) == 2) {
    return 1;
  }

  // For loop to convert to upper and set value ie A = 0 B = 1
  for (i = 0, j = strlen(keyWord[1]); i < j; i++) {
    cipher[i] = (toupper(keyWord[1][i]) - 65);
    printf("%i\n", cipher[i]);
  }

  // Prompt the user for the message to encrypt
  printf("Enter your secret message: ");
  fgets(message, 128, stdin);


  int keyCount = 0;
  int p = strlen(keyWord[1]);

  if (keyCount < p) {
    keyCount++;
  } else {
    keyCount = 0;
  }

  for (i = 0, k = strlen(message); i < k; i++) {
    if (isspace(message[i])) {
      printf(" ");
    } else if (isupper(message[i])) {
        char c = (message[i] - 65 + cipher[i])  % 26 + 65;
        printf("%c", c);
      }
      else {
        char d = (message[i] - 97 + cipher[i]) % 26 + 97;
        printf("%c", d);
      }
  }
}



// Function to check if alphabet characters.
int alphaCheck(char * argv[]) {
  int length = strlen(argv[1]), n;
  for (n = 0; n < length; n++) {
    if (!isalpha(argv[1][n])) {
      printf("Characters 'A-Z' for Keyword.\n");
      return 2;
    }
  }
}
```

The following section is redundant at the moment I left it in to show how I tried to tackle the problem but failed.

```
int keyCount = 0;
      int p = strlen(keyWord[1]);

      if (keyCount < p) {
        keyCount++;
      } else {
        keyCount = 0;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should enable more compiler warnings. For example, with gcc and my favorite set of flags (`-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wendif-labels -Wshadow -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wdisabled-optimization -O2`) I get:

```
$ cc prog.c
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:12:20: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘alphaCheck’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   if (argc != 2 || alphaCheck(keyWord) == 2) {
                    ^
prog.c:12:3: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘alphaCheck’ [-Wnested-externs]
   if (argc != 2 || alphaCheck(keyWord) == 2) {
   ^
prog.c:8:28: warning: unused variable ‘l’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int cipher[64], i, j, k, l;
                            ^
prog.c: At top level:
prog.c:53:5: warning: no previous prototype for ‘alphaCheck’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
 int alphaCheck(char * argv[]) {
     ^
prog.c: In function ‘alphaCheck’:
prog.c:61:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

All of these should be fixed:

- add `return 0` at the end of `alphaCheck`
- remove `l`
- put `int alphaCheck(char *[]);` before `main` (or move the whole function before `main` and make it `static`)

---

Your main loop has three cases. It checks for spaces, uppercase characters, and everything else is assumed to be a lowercase character. You should instead check for uppercase, lowercase, and pass everything else through unchanged (such as punctuation like `.` or `,`):

```
if (isupper(message[i])) {
    ...
} else if (islower(message[i])) {
    ...
} else {
    printf("%c", message[i]);
}
```

---

Your idea with `keyCount` isn't bad but it needs to be integrated with the main loop. That is, you should use `cipher[keyCount]` in the loop, not `cipher[i]`, and increment `keyCount` every time you use it like this.

Then, at the end of each iteration, you can do your check if you've run out of key (and reset `keyCount`):

```
for ( ... ) {
    ...

    if (keyCount >= p) {
        keyCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great, I will certainly add those flags when I run gcc. I currently only use -lm. I will implement the changes you have advised and these tips will hopefully be useful for future problem sets.

Comment: Added changes and can view here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/102737/vigeneres-cipher-in-c/104099#104099